# GAE: scheduled import of big gzipped file from a third party site

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm working on a Python web app that needs to import big (in terms of GAE limits) gzipped files from a third party site on regular basis. Think of rdf exports DMOZ project is producing on regular intervals.

This means daily fetching of a 500+ MB gzip file, gunzipping, parsing, processing and storing the results in GAE's datastore for later use.

What's the proper way to implement this functionality on GAE, having in mind the limits for maximum download, processing time, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit on downloaded file size in App Engine is currently 64MB. As a result, you've got two options:

- Use HTTP Range headers to download and process the file in chunks.
- Use an external service to do the download, split it into pieces, and send the pieces to your App Engine app.

Comment: You can't parse gzip in chunks, unfortunately. It has a header and you can't start reading it in the middle of a stream. Contrast with bzip2, which is block oriented.

Comment: @Spike Who said anything about reading it in chunks? You can read it as a stream; just fetch more data into the buffer each time you run out.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. Your proposal is basically to schedule a cron job that will que a task, that have to download the gz file chunk by chunk (chunksize < urlfetch size limits) as a stream, gunzip the stream, parse and store. And the task has to finish within 10 minutes. Is that right?

BTW: As per [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits), maximum response size for URL fetch is 32 megabytes. Where did you see 64MB?

Comment: @Nikolai That's right, except that there's no need for the cron job to schedule a task, really. You're correct that it's 32MB, not 64MB; my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

My initial gut reaction (without knowing what's inside the gzipped file) is to do the processing somewhere else (AWS?) and then pushed the processed data to your GAE application in small bits.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that solutions but I try to avoid systems administration. Otherwise, I could easily build my whole app on more conventional cloud platform like AWS. IMHO GAE is better than AWS. But AWS is better than GAE+AWS :)